# Get role with roles function

Tags: moodle

Is there a way to get all roles, including (id & rolename)

```
function getrole {
    $options = array();
    foreach (role_get_names() as $myrole) {
       $options[$myrole->id] = $myrole->localname;
    }
    return html_writer::select($options);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// The true at the end is used to return an array for select elements.
// So this returns an array with array(roleid => 'originalrolename')
$options = role_fix_names(get_all_roles(), context_system::instance(), ROLENAME_ORIGINAL, true);
```